# Why is monopropellant used?

Tags: propulsion, fuel, hydrogen, monopropellant

The most efficent fuel, liquid hydrogen, is a bipropellant. So, why don't we just use bipropellants? Some monopropellants, such as hydrazine, are toxic. Wouldn't it be easier to just use bipropellants like hydrogen and oxygen?

Comment: ...have you actually done any research into what is required to store liquid hydrogen on a spacecraft?

Comment: Yes. And is it easy to store store hydrazine?

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff

Comment: Rhetorical question: Why do some space vehicles use cold gas thrusters? The answer is simple: It's good enough. "Good enough" is a standard rule in engineering.

Comment: But, if bipropellant is better, then why use it instead. @DavidHammen

Comment: Requirements drive design.

Comment: But why would you make something worse for no reason, with no benefit to making that things instead @OrganicMarble

Comment: You wouldn't do that.

Comment: My point exactly. So, why don't we just use bipropellants. @OrganicMarble

Comment: "...have you actually done any research into what is required to store liquid hydrogen on a spacecraft?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134091/discussion-between-starship-is-go-for-launch-and-organic-marble).

Comment: I usually don't downvote right away, but I think there's been a series of un-researched questions in a homeworky-like style. [While there's nothing off-topic about that](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/984/12102) this kind of question really must include evidence of some level of prior research. So I've made a (hopefully) temporary and reversible downvote for lack of *evidence of research* https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNBYR.png

Comment: This is not unresearched, @uhoh

Comment: Okay I've changed to "evidence of research" (we vote on the post itself).  I'm having trouble with "Wouldn't it be easier...?" You're arguing a point that it would be easier and not higher efficiency, and yet you've shown no reason to suspect it might be. Bipropellant  schemes require twice as many tanks, valves, and sensors and may narrow the temperature range where neither freezes, boils or decomposes. What research have you done that suggests there is even a remote possibility that this could be "easier" as you suggest?

Comment: SpaceX uses cold gas thrusters for roll control on the thrusters being returned to the launch site or landing a barge. While the specific impulse from a cold gas thruster is even worse than that from a hot gas monopropellant, cold gas thrusters are good enough for SpaceX. The Space Shuttle used monopropellant hydrazine for its attitude control because it was good enough. "Good enough" is just that -- good enough to satisfy requirements. There's no reason to try for perfection if good enough is indeed good enough. Another way to say this is that perfection is the enemy of good enough.

Comment: The question is actually a quite fundamental one that deserves to get a decent answer by someone who knows the subject. As far as I know, one of the main reasons for using monopropellants is _reliability_; some monopropellant motors don't need an ignition source, a catalyzer is enough. But hypergolic motors don't need an ignition source either and are thus also quite reliable; so what's the advantage of monopropellants over hypergolics? Do monopropellant motors allow for shorter/more precise bursts than other motors, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until a more competent answer is written, here's an intermediate one:

Monopropellant motors are usually quite simple (in comparison to bipropellant motors). Simple designs with few moving parts mean less things can fail, these motors thus usually have high reliability, and usually also a lower weight than bipropellant motors. (I remember reading about a motor that had only one moving part in the whole design.)

If you don't use a hypergolic bipropellant, like hydrogen and oxygen you proposed, you also need a way to ignite the engine which further increases complexity and weight. Especially if the motor is meant to fire several times (like for attitude control) instead of just once.

If you only need a small amount of thrust, like attitude control of a satellite or spacecraft, the [good thrust-to-weight ratio](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14120/14549) and reliability of monopropellant engines makes them the best candidate for that particular job.